# Push another Viewcontroller from action button in xib file

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have a viewcontroller that presents from a `.xib`.
Inside the `.xib` there is a button; I want the button to pushviewcontroller to an other viewcontroller (`ViewControllerPeopleNew`).

I use an action button:

```
@IBAction func _hitPeople(sender: AnyObject) {
    let mapViewControllerObejct = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("peoplenew") as? ViewControllerPeopleNew
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(mapViewControllerObejct!, animated: false)
}
```

But got an error:

> Signal SIGABRT
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance

I already checked all about name identifier viewcontroller and all is right.

Comment: try printing your navigationController, make sure it is not null

Comment: Do not start a function name with _.

Comment: First of all a view controller that is instantiated from a xib doesn't belong to any storyboard. So it's self.storyboard is nil which means it can't instantiate a view controller from a storyboard because it doesn't know any.

Comment: how to handle it? @Adeel

Comment: there is no different if i start function name with _ or not @matt

Comment: I know that. So don't do it. Nevertheless, you will eventually figure out that the problem is the function name. You need to change the name and then delete the button action in the xib and form it all over again. It is the button action that is crashing you, not your code.

Comment: ok, thankyou for your advice @matt i already form it all over, and now i got _no error_ with code but seem like the button i pressed without any action, i put _breakpoint_ for this, the code running well step by step. but no action ( i mean not push another VC) what should I do ?

Comment: Is your view controller in navigation controller's stack? Are you sure that `self.navigationController` is not nil?

Comment: Of course it does nothing. Because `self.storyboard` is nil, as you were already told.

Answer (score 0):

From view controller present with XIB you can not get storyboad use below code

```
@IBAction func _hitPeople(sender: AnyObject) {

let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "storyboadname", bundle: nil)
let mapViewControllerObejct = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("peoplenew") as? ViewControllerPeopleNew
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(mapViewControllerObejct!, animated: false)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Always remember that you can only use `self.storyBoard` to instantiate a view controller when both the view controllers (`To and From view controllers`) belong to the same `storyboard`. If not then you need to first get a reference to the `storyboard` your `To view controller` belongs to. So you need to do this:

```
@IBAction func _hitPeople(sender: AnyObject) {
    let stotyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "YourStoryboard", bundle: nil)
    let mapViewControllerObejct = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("peoplenew") as? ViewControllerPeopleNew
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(mapViewControllerObejct!, animated: false)
}
```

PS: Just be sure that your `From view controller` is in the navigation stack i.e. `self.navigationController` is not `nil`.